# Tile Collision Question

Tags: tiles

I'm working on tile collision. Currently, I just draw the tile map the normal way (two for loops) and there is no scrolling. Right now, to check if my player is over a tile, I use `tileX = (int)person1v.X / 16;
tileY = (int)person1v.Y / 16;`
However, I want to detect collision *before* I hit the tile so it could act as a wall. How do I detect collision before even making the move?

Answer (score 0):

If the player moves **3** pixels at a time then check for:

```
leftTile = (int)(person1v.x - 3) / 16;
```

And for the tile to the right:

```
rightTile = (int)(person1v.x + 3 + 16) / 16;
```

Answer (score 0):

well instead of moving him first and checking for collision afterwards, check for collision for the future position of the character and if there is no collision then change the character's position.